# Android Developing: Canvas not displayed correctly

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

i'm new to android developing and tried to implement a simple game realized with a surface view and a canvas. I used the LunarView sample as a draft.

The idea is to have a human (movement controlled by touch event) and a zombie that follows him.

So far I have the following classes (i removed the from my point of view useless code):

1) MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

2) ZombieView with the innner class ZombieThread and Person (Person is only used to save data needly)

```
public class ZombieView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

//Thread Class that performs drawing on Canvas
class ZombieThread extends Thread {

    class Person {
        ...
    }

    private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private ZombieView zombieView;
    private Context context;
    private boolean running = false;

    //Canvas info
    private int mCanvasWidth = 1;
    private int mCanvasHeight = 1;
    private Bitmap mBackgroundImage;
    private final Drawable mHumanImage;
    private final Drawable mZombieImage;
    private Resources res;

    //Game Variables
    double hSpeed = 1;
    double zSpeed = 0.8;
    Person zombie;
    Person human;

    public ZombieThread(SurfaceHolder holder, ZombieView zombie, Context context) {
        this.surfaceHolder = holder;
        this.zombieView = zombie;
        this.context = context;

        this.zombie = new Person(100, 100, hSpeed);
        this.zombie.setRunning(true); //zombie always walks
        this.human = new Person(100, 200, zSpeed);

        res = context.getResources();
        mHumanImage = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_circle);
        mZombieImage = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_circle);
        mBackgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.background);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c = null;
        while (this.running) {

            try {
                c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    play();
                    onDraw(c);
                    checkCollision();

                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            try {
                sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkCollision() {
        //do something
    }

    public void play() {
        ...
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        //Do your drawing here...
      //  c.drawColor(Color.rgb(10, 0, 0));

        c.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
        c.save();

        //draw human and zombie
        int width = mHumanImage.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int height = mHumanImage.getIntrinsicHeight();

        mHumanImage.setBounds((int) human.getX() - (width / 2), (int) human.getY() - (height / 2),
                (int) human.getX() + (width / 2), (int) human.getY() + (height / 2));
        mHumanImage.draw(c);


        width = mZombieImage.getIntrinsicWidth();
        height = mZombieImage.getIntrinsicHeight();

        mZombieImage.setBounds((int) zombie.getX() - (width / 2), (int) zombie.getY() - (height / 2),
                (int) zombie.getX() + (width / 2), (int) zombie.getY() + (height / 2));
        mZombieImage.draw(c);

        c.restore();


    }

    public boolean doTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        //do something
    }

}

//ZombieView variables
private ZombieThread thread;
private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private Context context;

public ZombieView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    this.context = context;
    setFocusable(true); //makes sure we receive key-events
}

public ZombieView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    this.context = context;
    setFocusable(true); //makes sure we receive key-events
}

public ZombieView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    this.context = context;
    setFocusable(true); //makes sure we receive key-events
}

public ZombieThread getThread() {
    return thread;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread = new ZombieThread(surfaceHolder, this, context);
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.example.zombierun.zombierun.ZombieView android:background="#ccc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/customView" />
```

So my question now is the following:
When I start the App I see the Activity and a grey area which should be the canvas / surfaceview. Unfortunately that's all. But when I minimize the app by pushing the home button I see the canvas (with the images and background color) for the time the app minimizes. There are no errors displayed in logcat.

I assume that the canvas somehow stays in the background or that there is an overlay between different vies? Is this possible?

Hope someone can help me displaying the canvas correctly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use android:background="x" when working with a SurfaceView. You have to manually draw the color, in this case canvas.drawColor(Color.GREY) in your onDraw(Canvas c) call. Otherwise what you are doing is having the background color you set draw over your the surface of your surface view, rendering it an opaque grey. When onPause is called, the view is torn down and you momentarily are able to see the surface underneath the view's window overlay which painted #ccc.

Also: why are you sleeping the thread for 1/10 of a second every frame? You should remove this line. Or if you are trying to target a frame rate: realize 1000 ms / 100 ms = 10 frames, that is, you are drawing at ten fps.

Comment: Could you mark this as answered if it was the solution for you?